# Consuming HTTP POST method which is secured with Basic Auth in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http-post, spring-rest

I want to consume a post method which is secured using basicAuth. I am using springBoot, Spring RestTemplate to consume it.

I've tried like this:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", maxAge = 3600)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/ValidateAnswers", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<String> ValidateAnswers(@RequestBody Object requestIbject,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        final String uri = "foo:8080//validateAnswers";
// hiding full path here, 

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String plainClientCredentials = "user:pass";
        String base64ClientCredentials = new String(
                Base64.encodeBase64(plainClientCredentials.getBytes()));
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64ClientCredentials);

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters",
                headers);

        ResponseEntity<String> respEntity = restTemplate.postForObject(uri, requestIbject, String.class);
//              .exchange(uri,
//              HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
        System.err.println("=------------Response--------------");
        System.err.println("----" + respEntity);
        return respEntity;
    }
```

How do I pass the headers with basicAuth and post request body ?

Answer (score 1):

if you using spring > 4.3.1

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getInterceptors().add(new BasicAuthorizationInterceptor("user", "password"));
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code snippets I don't think you should use `post` method, try `get` first. And refer to my previous test:

```
public class Test {  

    private HttpHeaders getHeaders(){  
        String plainCredentials="admin:admin";  
        String base64Credentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(plainCredentials.getBytes());  
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();  
        headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);  
        return headers;  
    }  

    @Test  
    public void testLogin() {  
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();  
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(getHeaders());  
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/login", HttpMethod.GET,  
                request, String.class);  
        System.out.println(response.getBody());  
    }  
}
```